# httppost android problems

Tags: android, http-post

I know there are other posts on this topic, but I have been trying to figure this out for a week with no avail.

Here is my code to connect to a server through android:

```
public String postQuery(String queryString, String jsonData, String [][]jsonDataArray){

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://myapp.com/app.php");

    String tempLine = "";

    try {

      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("a_token", "SDFSDF"));
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("d_id", "S34S"));

      post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

      StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
      int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

      String line = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        tempLine = tempLine + line;
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tempLine;
}
```

The code on my server looks like this:

```
Token: <?php echo $_POST["a_token"]; ?><br />
ID: <?php echo $_POST["d_id"]; ?><br />

Let's print out the entire Post:
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

My android activity then calls the following:

```
String result = serverClient.postQuery(query, jsonData2, jsonData);
Toast.makeText(InterestsActivity.this, "" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

What's then displayed on my android device is:

```
Token:</br>ID:</br>Let's print out the entire Post: Array()
```

Can anyone figure out why my Post data is not being transmitted to the server?  Thanks in advance